# Can't access Vue instance inside return jsx

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I made a **Table** component and inside every column I've put **jsx syntax return function to render the HTML**, but inside return of render, I want to change data of component with `this.firstName = item ;` (**item is inside render function**) but I can't access **this**.
How can I access **this** inside return of render in Vue.js ?
here is my code :

```js
field: 'id',
caption: '',
sortable: false,
render: (item) => (h) => {
  return (
    <td class="uk-text-middle uk-text-center">
      <div class="uk-inline">
        <span class="more-option" uk-icon="icon: more"></span>
        <div class="uk-padding-small" uk-dropdown="mode: click">
          <ul class="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav uk-text-right">
            <li>
              <button onClick={ () => {console.log(this)} }>
                <span class="uk-margin-small-left" uk-icon="icon: file-edit"></span>
                edit
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <span class="uk-margin-small-left" uk-icon="icon: trash"></span>
                delete
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use nested anonymous functions, the internal function scope of `this` is different. 
You can bind `this`, or assign `this` to another variable in upper function

```js
(item) => {
  const self = this;
  
  return (h) => (
  
    <button onClick={ () => {console.log(self)} }>
      <span class="uk-margin-small-left" uk-icon="icon: file-edit"></span>
      edit
    </button>
  );
}
```